# Android shared element transition

Tags: android, objectanimator

I want to implement shared element transaction with pulse animation. 
When you click Activity1 red button, it must fill entire space with pulse animation from redButton position. 
After the screen is filled, the activity2 shows additional UI like buttons or editTexts.

I tried to use ObjectAnimator, but i don't understand which better way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `scene transitions` is better

Here is a sample demo from google, take a look:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActivitySceneTransitionBasic